# How to inject and execute a javascript function without modifiting document in webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I could simply do :

```
object DomElement = ChooseMyDomElement(webBrowser1);  //this is a ID less element
webBrowser1.DocumentText = NewDocumentTextWithInjectedJavaScriptFunction;
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("myfnc", DomElement);
```

However I don't want to make any modification to loaded document like set `DocumentText`, Create a new script element, etc..

Here is that I tried :

```
object DomElement = ChooseMyDomElement(webBrowser1);  //this is a ID less element
var js = "function myfnc(r) {alert(r);}  myfnc(" + DomElement +");"; //DomElement is converted to string!
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { js });
```

The problem is that java sees `DomElement` as string!
I want to send `DomElement` object with a javascript function to do processing on `DomElement` in the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var anyScripts = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("script");
    if (anyScripts == null || anyScripts.Count == 0)
    {
        // at least one <script> element must be present for eval to work
        var script = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(script);
    }

    // use anonymous functions

    dynamic func = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { 
        "(function() { return function(elem, color) { elem.style.backgroundColor = color; } })()" });

    var body = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement;

    func(body, "red");
}
```

Comment: Wooah! You are really a expert with WebBrowser technologies! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should execute javascript in the control without having to alter the document:

```
 BrowserControl.Navigate("javascript:function test(){console.log('test');}test();")
```

Comment: I don't think it will change the Document Text - but I believe you would be limited by the maximum url length.